# For Each...Next with or without element difference

Tags: vba, excel, loops, foreach

In a `For Each` Loop is there a difference if we add the element in question after the `Next` statement ?

In other words, what's the difference between those two following valid ways ?

```
For Each Element in MyCollection
'...code
Next

For Each Element in MyCollection
'...code
Next Element
```

Comment: As far as I'm aware, this is purely to make it easier to read and keep track of your nesting. Not much difference above, but in code with lots of nested loops it really does help. (as does indentation)

Comment: A quick google would have shown the answer to this. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx. `You can optionally specify element in the Next statement. This improves the readability of your program, especially if you have nested For Each loops. You must specify the same variable as the one that appears in the corresponding For Each statement.`

Comment: Ok thanks for that information !

Answer (score 0):

It is optional to add the variable name. Although I would suggest you pick your / your organisations preferred way and consistently stick with it